# Puma config.rb require

Tags: config, require, puma

I have the following directory structure:

```
|-app
|-config
|---puma
|-----base.rb
|-----development.rb
|-----production.rb
```

To keep `development.rb` & `production.rb` DRY, I added `require_relative 'base'` at the top of each file. `base.rb` contains the configurations common to both environments.

But, `foreman start` exits with this error:

```
base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `workers' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
development.rb:1:in `require_relative'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE

The [`import` directive was added to the config file for Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/916) 3.1.0.

---

#### Workaround

Replace `require_relative 'base'` with `eval(File.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'base.rb')))`.

#### Explanation

To [load your config file, Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/32b1fb3742e5918e0e79ee705b48c912a1f0742d/lib/puma/dsl.rb#L24) does an [instance_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) on its contents. So, the configuration methods in your config file, get called on the `Puma::DSL` object.

However, "require loads the file into the global namespace rather than
into the scope of the calling code" ([require in instance_eval](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/317044)). So, using `require_relative` causes the configuration methods in `base.rb` to get called on `main:Object` rather than on the `Puma::DSL` object, hence the error.

#### Enhancement

Maybe Puma could add methods to their DSL (perhaps called `import` & `import_relative`) that make this easier & cleaner.